# numpy genfromtxt issues in Python3

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, genfromtxt

I'm trying to use `genfromtxt` with Python3 to read a simple *csv* file containing strings and numbers. For example, something like (hereinafter "test.csv"):

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

with Python2, the following works well:

```
import numpy
data=numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=None)
# Now data is something like [(1, 'a') (2, 'b') (3, 'c')]
```

in Python3 the same code returns `[(1, b'a') (2, b'b') (3, b'c')]`. This is somehow [expected](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) due to the different way Python3 reads the files. Therefore I use a converter to decode the strings:

```
decodef = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8")
data=numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype="f8,S8", converters={1: decodef})
```

This works with Python2, but not with Python3 (same `[(1, b'a') (2, b'b') (3, b'c')]` output.
However, if in Python3 I use the code above to read only one column:

```
data=numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(1,), dtype="S8", converters={1: decodef})
```

the output strings are `['a' 'b' 'c']`, already decoded as expected.

I've also tried to provide the file as the output of an `open` with the `'rb'` mode, as suggested at [this link](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/978888), but there are no improvements.

Why the converter works when only one column is read, and not when two columns are read? Could you please suggest me the correct way to use `genfromtxt` in Python3? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @wim Edited. Now the question should look more clear.

Comment: Same issue here. I was very confused at first by the use of bytes b' literal, instead of an expected string. I had csv file with 2 columns:  sentiment with 0 or 1 value; and text (UTF-16) 
Handling the columns separately using this decoding approach was viable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to my problem is using the `dtype` for unicode strings (`U2`, for example).

Thanks to the answer of E.Kehler, I found the solution.
If I use `str` in place of `S8` in the `dtype` definition, then the output for the 2nd column is empty:

```
numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype='f8,str')
```

the output is:

```
array([(1.0, ''), (2.0, ''), (3.0, '')], dtype=[('f0', '<f16'), ('f1', '<U0')])
```

This suggested me that correct `dtype` to solve my problem is an unicode string:

```
numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype='f8,U2')
```

that gives the expected output:

```
array([(1.0, 'a'), (2.0, 'b'), (3.0, 'c')], dtype=[('f0', '<f16'), ('f1', '<U2')])
```

Useful information can be also found at [the numpy datatype doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) .

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, writing

> dtype="S8"

(or any variation of "S#") in NumPy's genfromtxt yields a byte string. To avoid this and get just an old fashioned string, write

> dtype=str

instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it didn't solved my problem, because using `str` the output of: `numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype='f8,str')` gives an empty string for the data in the 2nd column (and a `dtype` `<U0`). This helped me to find an answer (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
training = np.genfromtxt('twitter_train.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(0,1), dtype='U')
```

In my case, the first column contains a sentiment value of either 0 or 1 and the second column is a string of many characters representing a tweet in this ex. 
**dtype='U'** removed the b' from being included.

So in your case it would be: 
data=numpy.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", dtype='U')