# numpy genfromtxt issues with .txt input

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to import a txt with strings and number columns using numpy.genfromtxt function. Essentially I need an array of strings. Here is a sample txt giving me trouble:

```
    H2S 1.4
    C1  3.6
```

The txt is codified as unicode. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np          
decodf= lambda x: x.decode('utf-16')
sample = np.genfromtxt(('ztest.txt'), dtype=str,
                        converters = {0:decodf, 1:decodf},
                                     delimiter='\t',
                                     usecols=0)
print(sample)
```

Here's the output:

```
['H2S' 'None']
```

I've tried several ways to fix this issue. By putting dtype=None and eliminating the converter, I get:

```
[b'\xff\xfeH\x002\x00S' b'\x00g\x00\xe8\x00n']
```

I also tried eliminating the converter and putting dtype=str and got:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I understand this is a troublesome function. I saw different options 
(eg: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581070/numpy-genfromtxt-issues-in-python3)) but couldn't get anyone to work.

What am I doing wrong? In the meantime, I'm looking into Pandas...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your file is encoded as UTF-16, and the first two characters are the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Try this (with python 2.7):

```
import io
import numpy as np

with io.open('ztest.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-16') as f:
    data = np.genfromtxt(f, delimiter='\t', dtype=None, usecols=[0])  # or dtype=str
```

`genfromtxt` has some issues when run in python 3 with Unicode files.  As a work-around, you could simply encode the lines before before passing them to `genfromtxt`.  For example, the following encodes each line as latin-1 before passing the lines to `genfromtxt`:

```
import io
import numpy as np

with io.open('ztest.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-16') as f:
    lines = [line.encode('latin-1') for line in f]
    data = np.genfromtxt(lines, delimiter='\t', dtype=None, usecols=[0])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Your code yields `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Ah, right.  I was using python 2.7.  I get the same error when I use python 3.4.