# Missing spaces in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to read a unicode data file to a few lists. I have a mixed unicode/integer/float data file of this format:

```
Է   1335    1.1
դ   1380    1.2
    32  1.3
ն   1398    1.4
ե   1381    1.5
ր   1408    1.6
```

I am reading the file with `numpy genfromtxt` according to this question [numpy.genfromtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581070/numpy-genfromtxt-issues-in-python3):

```
decodef = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8")
arr = np.genfromtxt("./data_files/data", delimiter="\t", dtype="U1, i4, f8", converters={0: decodef})
```

This gives me a `numpy.ndarray` not containing spaces, but empty elements for spaces in the first column:

```
('Է', 1335, 1.1)
('դ', 1380, 1.2)
('', 32, 1.3)
('ն', 1398, 1.4)
('ե', 1381, 1.5)
('ր', 1408, 1.6)
```

I have already tried to solve the space issue with `autostrip=False (the default value)`,  `missing_values=" "`, `replace_space='_'` parameters, but still get the same array with empty items for the spaces. I guess all this parameters are intended only for delimiter manipulation?!

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Python version 3.4.5 is being used.

Comment: What is the problem?  This is a structured array.  The empty string in the 3rd record?  Given the dtype the array display looks normal.

Comment: Yes, the empty string in the third record. For other symbols everything works as expected. Edited that part to clarify. )

Comment: Some parameters apply to field names, not values.  Is there a fill value parameter?

Comment: No, no fill value parameter is set.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the genfromtxt method somehow removes the space.

If you use

```
decodef = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8") if x != '' else " "
arr = np.genfromtxt("text", delimiter="\t", dtype="U1, i4, f8",converters={0: decodef})
```

It works. 
I still do not exactly understand why though.

Comment: Hm. It didn't work for me.
P.S. I am using Python 3.4.5. Don't know does this matter in this particular case or not.

Comment: Indeed, did this using 2.7 and it is not working in 3.4.5 ^^

Comment: Obvious (but upmost ugly):

    decodef = lambda x: x.decode("utf-8") if x.decode("utf-8") != '' else " "

Comment: Do you really need to use np.genfromtxt ?

Comment: With separate decoding it works. :)
I were not able to make it work in other ways. Even though after getting it done with `genfromtxt` haven't looked back to previous approaches once more.